# I developed a wordpress plugin got an unusual error suddenly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a custom plugin in wordpress it was working fine but suddenly I got an unusual error stated as follows

```
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in /public_html/demo2/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-custom/inc/admin/Settings.php on line 7
```

Here is what goes goes under line 7

```
<?php
/**
 * @package My Custom Plugin
 */ 

namespace Inc\admin;

class Settings {
    public function register() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_menu' ) );
    }
}
```

Can anyone could help me out with this issue what exactly is going on I am really much confused

Comment: If there is no issue with namespace then you can try inserting `namespace Inc\admin;` after `<?php` [Maybe the 2nd line]

Comment: See if there's a [leading space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220037/231316).

Comment: @AkhtarujjamanShuvo can you please put this as answer it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no issue with namespace then you can try inserting `namespace Inc\admin;` after `<?php` [Maybe the 2nd line]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the white spaces thank you